# VS Code trying to push to deleted repository

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I am trying to push to a remote GitHub repo using VSCode (Techsercise.git).  For some reason, it's trying to push to an old, deleted repository (Tech1.git), even though the output when I run git remote looks correct.

How can I change the target repository in VS Code?

From terminal

```
PS C:\Users\~\Projects\Techsercise> git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/~/Techsercise.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/~/Techsercise.git (push)
```

From VS Code

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/~/Tech1.git/' not found
```

Comment: which repo is used when you push from the command line? If you search `.git` can you find a file with `Tech1`?

Comment: Did you try to push from terminal ??

Comment: I did, and that works fine.  I assume that VS Code is getting the origin from the git config, right?  Does it cache it anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to update your remote url path.

Try `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/yourusername/YOURREPO.git`

Afterwards, you can verify with `$ git remote -v` to print that it's pointing to the right repo.

Comment: As I indicated in the above question, `git remote -v` does show the correct origin.